# Keras model with multiple level dimensions in input data

Tags: r, keras

I would like to build a Keras model to understand what drives profitability in a multi-dimensional data context. The challenge that I have is on how to approach this.

I have a dataset that has the structure below. The third object include the 'result' variable and I would like to use all the other variables to predict this. Between "Wheels" and "Taxi trip" and "Passengers" and "Taxi trip" there is a one-to-many relationship. Thus, one taxi has more wheels (usually 4) and one or more passengers on board.

```
Wheels:
 - Position
 - pressure
 - ... etc ...
 - KEY_taxitrip

Passengers:
 - Seat
 - Weight of passenger
 - Name
 - ... etc ...
 - KEY_taxitrip

Taxi trip:
 - KEY_taxitrip
 - Profit
 - Car
 - Brand
 - From location
 - Two location
 - ... etc ...
```

The approach that I have been thinking about is to flatten the data, but this will lead to multiple instances of each "taxi trip" and furthermore the possible interaction between the "wheels" and the "Passenger" values will be eliminated. Also this will make it hard to use it for predictions.

Does anybody have any recommendation on literature on keras solution design for this type of problems?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is called multiple input in LSTM 
And you can find different structures in this post: https://machinelearningmastery.com/keras-functional-api-deep-learning/

Experts may have better answer though..